# Flash drive dead empty - void

Tags: partitioning, usb, flash, chromium

I tried to write chromium image to my flash drive. The writing turned out horribly.
The flash drive is empty - and by empty i mean empty - it is listed on lsusb but fdisk -l wont show it. My theory is that it doesn't have proper partition table or partitions.

---

Note: i have used this USB for a year to install Linux distributions and have used chromium on it...

Comment: UPDATE: i used parted and the usb showed up however i got another problem.
-created partition table
-when creating partition it says that 1 is outside the device :(

Comment: OUTPUT OF - sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 512 B, 512 bytes, 1 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1ca2291b